# How to troublshoot updating to MSOLEDBSQL driver that is breaking macro-enabled Excel book?

Tags: sql-server, excel, oledb, vba

I have an Excel macro-enabled file (.xlsm) with VBA that builds various SELECT statements and also executes a stored procedure on a SQL Server DB in order to populate a table. It is from a legacy system and uses an old deprecated driver (MSOLEDB.1), and I am trying to update it to read from a new database, while updating the driver as well.

I've updated the new connection string in the VBA code from using Provider=MSOLEDB.1 to the new MSOLEDBSQL driver (which is installed on new SQL Server). I can step through the code and all executes perfectly. I can run the macro from the refresh button on the sheet, all good. *But when I save and close the file, and then attempt to re-open it - upon hitting Enable for the macro warning, it hangs excel.* When I change it back to the old string, all works fine again- I can close and reopen the file, and re-run the code with no issues.

I can include more detail about both old and new environment, but I wanted to see if anyone even has any suggestions of how to troubleshoot this. The key difference is that old string authenticated via SQL login and the new one via Windows. (I don't want to authenticate via SQL login moving forward.)

Old (sensitive data replaced):
**"PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;DATA SOURCE=#.#.#.#\SQLEXPRESS;INITIAL CATALOG=Databasename;NETWORK=DBMSSOCN;USER ID=SQLUser;PASSWORD=password;"**

New:
**"Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=servername;Database=Databasename;Trusted_Connection=yes"**

Running Debug->Compile VBA Project has sorted out buggy things like this before, but not this time. I've tried recompiling every sheet with code (even added comments to sheets with no codes so I could recompile them) but no effect.

I also tried adding the ForceVBALoadFromSource from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3085435/august-8-2017-update-for-excel-2016-kb3085435 which had no effect.

I believe it has either something to do with the new driver with Windows authentication, but I am really hoping for some hints.

Comment: Do you see any error log on SQL Server log or Windows Event Viewer? And what happens if you use SQL Server login with the new driver? (since you don't know what's causing the error, it is important to be sure if that Windows Authentication has something to do with the problem).

Comment: @Ronaldo Thanks very much for that suggestion- I can successfully use SQL Login credentials to connect and run the applications, without any issue. When I change it to Windows (by replacing the user/pass with 'TrustedConnection=Yes', it hangs. When I look at the log I see: Source: Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing Message: "An account was successfully logged on"- at that timestamp, and it references my Windows username. In the Event Viewer, I see only 'Audit Success' successful logons. Am I missing where to see fails or errors?

Comment: You might be missing SQL Server log. That **Source: Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing** doesn't look like a SQL Server log message. You can find it on `yourdatabase > Management > SQL Server logs > Current`.

Comment: I think the solution had partially to do with orphaned users. I found on old tip from 14 years ago :) I gave the \Domain Users login sysadmin, and the problem went away. Then I removed sysadmin, and the problem stayed gone. I checked and the SIDs were identical, but it's like some association needed refreshing. It's annoying when you fix something but not entirely sure how, so I'd appreciate any other insights. Thanks again!